# Why is there no ARM in Scala stdlib?

Tags: scala, resource-management

Why is there no ARM (like Clojure's `with-open`) provided in the Scala standard library?

Comment: The [arm tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/arm/info) is meant for questions about the ARM processor architecture, so I removed it.

Comment: Not exactly an answer to your question, but there is such a project: https://github.com/jsuereth/scala-arm

Comment: was this a fire-and-forget trolling question?

Answer (score 11):

**Short answer**

Because nobody's added one yet!

**Longer answer**

Many proposals for a bigger better I/O library have been put forward, but the best API to use has proved controversial.
In particular, the exact way to handle newlines when reading a file line-by-line is a sensitive subject. *(e.g. should they be stripped, or passed through as-is?  If stripped, should empty lines be skipped over?)*

This tends to encourage third-party libraries favouring different needs.

Having said all that... You may want to check out jsuereth's offering on github: https://github.com/jsuereth/scala-arm/wiki

Comment: That library is designed to be contributed back to scala's core.  Everything in it is 100% compatible with the Scala license and all contributers have signed EPFL's contributor agreement.  So it's the best place to contribute if you want to see ARM enter Scala's core library.